# Where do I add a custom `index do...end` block for ActiveAdmin comments page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm building an ActiveAdmin panel in RoR, and I'm running into an issue customizing the comments page. With any other resource, it's as easy as specifying a block in `app/admin/resource.rb` as follows:

```
index do
    column :someattribute
end
```

But there isn't an `app/admin/comment.rb` file for me to add that `index` block into. So, where is that block supposed to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `active_admin.rb` (`app/config/initializers` directory) just set to true this:
`config.allow_comments = true` #so you can comment

and

`config.show_comments_in_menu = true` #so that Comments tab appears in the navigation bar.

To customize it, create `active_admin_comments.rb` under app/admin/ directory:

```
ActiveAdmin.register ActiveAdmin::Comment, as: 'Comment' do
  # your  logic here
end
```

This should solve the issue.